# Force xargs to stop on first command error

Tags: find, xargs

I'm running a command to find all make files in a directory and run `make build`.

I would like to get `xargs` to stop on the first `make build` that fails.

Here's the command I have so far.

```
$ find . -name "Makefile" | xargs dirname | xargs -I {} make -C {} build
```

The problem is that `xargs` keeps going even after a `make build` fails. When I check the final status code, here's what I see.

```
$ echo $?
123
```

And when I checked the man page. Here's what it says.

```
123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125
```

Which makes sense because some of those `make build`s failed with exit 1 or something.

Is there a way to get `xargs` to stop on the first `make build` error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> XARGS(1):
>
> > If any invocation of the command exits with a status of 255, xargs will stop immediately without reading any further input.

It would be possible to use a subshell to return `255`:

```
find . -name "Makefile" | xargs dirname | \
  xargs -I {} sh -c 'make -C "$1" build || exit 255' sh {}
```

Comment: Aaah, okay. I was thinking there would be some extra flag or something as part of `xargs` itself. This works too though!